# how can we get BUSINESS Address in MAPI using C++?

Tags: c++, mfc

When i used **PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_STREET** MAPI Constants but It get **HOME** Address street.

- When I used **PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_STREET** it get **HOME** address street ...
- When I used **PR_HOME_ADDRESS_STREET** it get **HOME** address street ...
- When I used **PR_OTHER_ADDRESS_STREET** it get **OTHER** address street ...

how we can retrieve BUSINESS Address ?

[image: C++ Code screen short]

[image: Business address Screen Short]

[image: Home address Screen Short]

Comment: have you tried to use IDs directly, i.e. Business: 8045
Home: 3A5D (PR_HOME_ADDRESS_STREET)
Other: 3A63 (PR_OTHER_ADDRESS_STREET)
Mailing: 3A29 (PR_STREET_ADDRESS and PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_STREET)